# Single Writer and Multiple Readers for Ole storage file

Tags: visual-c++, ole

I have an Ole storage file which needs to be write by a writer and read by multiple readers. When i try to open stream with CFile::shareDenyWrite it's not opening stream. It's returning false.Stream is opening if i use shareEcxlusive but than i have to make storage file share Exclusive.
Is there any way to open OleStorage files with one writer and multiple readers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should be using StgOpenStorageEx to work with OleStorage files NOT CFile. Read the comments on STGM_DIRECT_SWMR (Single Writer Multiple Readers) for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You'll need to make sure that you've initialized COM before using COM based functions (just add AfxOleInit() in your InitInstance and the framework handles the start-up and shut-down).